# insert one grades to each person

Tags: mysql, insert

thanks for the answers earlier.. :)

i have these tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employee` ( 
`ssn` int(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(30)
);

INSERT INTO `employee` VALUES (102,'Emily'), (112,'John'), (122,'Sean');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `graduate` ( 
`id` int(11) PRIMARY KEY,
`level` varchar(30)
);

INSERT INTO `graduate` VALUES (1,'Elementary'), (2,'Junior'), (3,'Senior'), (4,'Bachelor');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `detail` ( 
`ssn` int(11) PRIMARY KEY,
`id_level` int(11),
FOREIGN KEY (`ssn`) REFERENCES `employee`(`ssn`),
FOREIGN KEY (`id_level`) REFERENCES `graduate`(`id`)
);
```

I'm trying to insert different level for each employee, e.g. inserting John who graduated from elementary, junior, senior and insert Emily who graduated from all the level. but it got error. it said duplicate entry of ssn

Comment: Which query is throwing the error?

Comment: insert into detail query, but it's done now.. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

detail table should have both ssn and id_level as primary key.

Comment: Since you try to insert more than one educational level for each employee and have the detail table with ssn as primary key, you get a duplicate ssn which causes the error.

Comment: Ah ok thanks for clarifying. I don't see a query to `INSERT` into the `detail` table in the OP's code, but I guess it can be assumed.